# How to get Bamboo IP address

Tags: ip, pipeline, devops, bamboo

how can I get the IP address for bamboo?

This is not hosted on my machine. I just have an address. I tried using "host to ip" tool http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.htm
but it doesn't seems working, I assume there is dynamic IP for the bamboo, can we get it

Comment: You may want to make your question more general, like, "How to find the IP address of any website".

Comment: Hi @ricksuggs this is hosted some other machine which is not accessible publicly

Answer (score 0):

In case your deployment is located on your own network the following commands would provide you the internal ip address:

**On Windows**

```
ipconfig
```

**On Linux/MacOS**

```
ifconfig
```

Alternatively, you could run the following against your Bamboo instance as it will provide the IP address:

> # [BAMBOO-DNS], i.e.: http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.htm

```
ping [BAMBOO-DNS]
```

Comment: Hi @Vadim-kotov i dont have access to the machine